# DPM 2012 cannot create offsite backup of Exchange 2010

Tags: exchange-2010, scdpm

I am using System Center 2012 Data Protection Manager installed on a Windows Server 2012.

I use the Azure DPM agent to upload offsite backups to Azure.

I have an issue with Exchange 2010 (running in Windows Server 2008 R2). I can create a replica and keep it protected with short-term disk-based backup but when I try to add online protection for this group (the group contains only Exchange database backup) I get the message “This option is disabled as this protection group does not contain data sources that can be protected online”.

Anyone know why not ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can only You can provide online protection for Hyper-V, SQL and File, as stated here http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn296608.aspx & http://blogs.technet.com/b/systemcenter/archive/2014/03/16/using-azure-backup-with-dpm.aspx